# Pandas pivot table raise KeyError(i)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm just trying out the pivot_table code in pandas. I have a Dataframe below:

```
Device Name   Remark
NodeX         Hardware
NodeX         Software
NodeY         Hardware
NodeY         Hardware
NodeZ         Software
NodeZ         Software
```

and expected output of the pivot table is the total count for each category in 'Remark' for each 'Device Name':

```
Device Name  Hardware   Software
NodeX        1          1
NodeY        2          0
NodeZ        0          2
```

the code for pivot_table is

```
dfsummary = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Device Name'], columns='Remark', values=['Hardware', 'Software'], aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
```

but I'm receiving this error:

```
...., in pivot_table raise KeyError(i)
KeyError: 'Hardware'
```

This is an example of a similar scenario that I'm facing when using pivot_table.

Comment: that's because it isn't a column, change it to `Remark` and it should work

Comment: @Datanovice you mean ```dfsummary = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Device Name'], columns='Remark', values=['Remark'], aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)```? Cause I'm now getting ```ValueError: Grouper for 'Remark' not 1-dimensional```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='Device Name', columns='Remark', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Or `pd.pivot_table(df, index='Device Name', columns='Remark', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)`

Comment: I think `count` won't give correct ans. in this case.

Comment: Oh right! I was experimenting with a column named `count` and accidentally the `agg_func` took that in. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df['Device Name'], df['Remark'])
```

Output:

```
Remark       Hardware  Software
Device Name                    
NodeX               1         1
NodeY               2         0
NodeZ               0         2
```